# Unable to use Google Places API in android webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

I'm trying to build a web view app for a site and I have added the places API with key and tested. It works fine.

But when I built the app in web view the places API didn't work.

Here's my Code :

[**Activity:**](https://codeshare.io/X8DvWK)

[**Manifest:**](https://codeshare.io/DZK7rk)

Any help is greatly appreciated.